# Can I write an enum/union/object and treat it as both a type and a value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am currently in the process of writing a React application in TypeScript and would like to have good types on the data that I retrieve from the server. I'm still new to TypeScript so I don't know if this is even possible, but if so, I'd like to be able to write my data in either of the below fashions:

```js
// Enum
export enum SaleStatus {
  OPEN = "open",
  CLOSED = "closed",
  PENDING = "pending"
}

// Implementation
interface Sale {
  status: SaleStatus;
}

// Server Payload
{
  status: "open"
}

// Redux dispatchers/Jest mocks/anything where I can create those payloads myself
// VALID
const sale: Sale = {
  status: SaleStatus.OPEN
}

// Same as above, except using the values instead of the Enum
// INVALID
const sale: Sale = {
  status: "open" // TS2322: Type '"open"' is not assignable to type 'SaleStatus'.
}

// Generic actions like comparisons
if (sale.status === SaleStatus.OPEN) {
  foo();
}
```

The closest I've been able to get is by writing [Objects as consts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums) which looks like the following:

```js
export const SaleStatus = {
  OPEN: "open",
  CLOSED: "closed",
  PENDING: "pending"
} as const;

export type SaleStatusType = typeof SaleStatus[keyof typeof SaleStatus];

// Implementation
interface Sale {
  status: SaleStatusType;
}

// Valid
const sale: Sale = {
  status: SaleStatus.OPEN
};

// Valid
const sale: Sale = {
  status: "open"
};
```

This works and if there's no other way, this is what I'll be using but if possible, I'd like to avoid writing both an object and a type. Instead, it would be preferable to use just the SaleStatus object/enum/union/whatever else as the type of the status property and be able to use it for data comparison.

Comment: You'd have to cast `"open" as SaleStatus`

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? It is unclear to me what's not working, as both examples are actually equivalent more or less.

Comment: @JonasWilms In the first code block where I define the status of sale as a string "open", I get a TS error: `TS2322: Type '"open"' is not assignable to type 'SaleStatus'`. If I cast "open" to SaleStatus like you suggested above, it works but I'd like to have it do that automatically for me if possible.

Answer (score 1):

To quote [Ryan Cavanough](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17690#issuecomment-321319291):

> The intent of string enums is that the values of the enum are opaque (i.e. they can be changed behind the scenes without breaking consumers). If you don't want that behavior, it's easy enough to use the pre-string-enum workarounds to create similar union types.

That's why string literal types are not assignable to enum types (although they are technically equivalent). You always need an explicit typecast:

```
"open" as SaleStatus
```

or build your own "enum" as you already did.

Comment: Ah I understand now, thank you. Yeah I don't have to use enums if it's not compatible with my use case (I'm the one writing all the types at work so I have all the say :P). Would you happen to know of any way to merge the object and type definitions from the second example in my question into like a one liner so TS knows to treat it as both and object and a type?

Comment: Yeah, just `export type SaleStatus = ...` should work. Types and Variables live in different namespaces and can have the same name (that's in fact how enums / classes work)

Answer (score 0):

As Jonas Wilms has suggested already, there needs to be some sort of casting for this to work. You could just cast the whole incoming object to Sale instead of the status field. Here is how I'd solve it:

```
enum SaleStatus {
  OPEN = "open",
  CLOSED = "closed",
  PENDING = "pending"
}

interface Sale {
  status: SaleStatus
}

// Incoming sale object from server...
const sale = {
  status: "open"
} as Sale;
// ... can be casted to Sale object without additional internal casting.

if (sale.status === SaleStatus.OPEN) {
  foo();
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that, as that cast possibly also hides other mistakes, also it is quite unclear to the reader why the cast is needed.

Comment: This approach works but like @JonasWilms said, it isn't immediately apparent to the reader why we do this. I'm trying to make the code as concise and simple to understand as possible to increase TypeScript adoption at my company

Comment: @KasimAhmic for data you're loading from the server, it would actually be something like `const sale: Sale = JSON.parse(…)`, no?

Comment: @Bergi Correct and the server part is actually taken care of for us by RTK Query so I'm not really concerned about that. Since we work with the data on the front end application, I need good typings for when we write comparisons, mutate the data, send data back to the server, etc.